# Passing structures to functions c

Tags: c, arrays, function, structure

I'm trying to wite a code that would create an array of structures. I'm still at the early stages where I am trying to pass the structure to a function and though I figured pointer would have to be utitlized, I just can't figure out how to do it the correctly. Here's my code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct age{
    int num;
};

struct name{
    char fname [15];
    char lname[15];
    struct age nameAge;
};

void input(struct name *info[]);

int main (void){
char choice;
char ans;
int i;
struct name record[10];
do{
    printf("M E N U");
    printf("\n\n[I]nput\n[D]isplay\n[S]earch\n[Q]uit");
    printf("\n\nEnter choice: ");
    choice=tolower(getche());
    system("cls");

    switch (choice){
        case 'i': input(&record[]);
                  i++;
                break;
        case 'd': //function here
                break;
        case 's': //fucntion here
                break;
        case 'q': printf("The program will now close.");
                break;
        default: printf("Invalid character. Try again");
                break;
        }

    getch();
    system("cls");

   }while (choice!='q');
return 0;
}

void input(struct name *info[]){
//codes here
}
```

Comment: Why `input(&record[]);`??

Comment: Aside: you need to `#include` more library headers - `ctype.h`, `conio.h` and `stdlib.h` at least. You should be getting compiler warnings. And `char choice;` should be `int choice;` same as the return type of `getche` and `tolower`.

Comment: Note: You haven't initialized `i`.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that **The name of an array "decays" to a pointer to its first element**. So, in your case, just use `record` to pass the "array" (You can't really pass an array) to the function. You also need to change the function argument type to `struct info*` as `record` is of type `struct info*`.

Here is the working code with the changes commented:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct age{
    int num;
};

struct name{
    char fname[15];
    char lname[15];
    struct age nameAge;
};

/*void input(struct name *info[]);  Note the change in the declaration */
void input(struct name *info);

int main (void){
    char choice;
    char ans;
    int i;
    struct name record[10];
    do{
        printf("M E N U");
        printf("\n\n[I]nput\n[D]isplay\n[S]earch\n[Q]uit");
        printf("\n\nEnter choice: ");
        choice=tolower(getche());
        system("cls");

        switch (choice){
            case 'i': input(record); /* Note the change here as well */
                      i++;
                    break;
            case 'd': //function here
                    break;
            case 's': //fucntion here
                    break;
            case 'q': printf("The program will now close.");
                    break;
            default: printf("Invalid character. Try again");
                    break;
            }

        getch();
        system("cls");

       }while (choice!='q');
    return 0;
}

void input(struct name *info){ /* Note the change here in the function definition too */
    //codes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the function definition and implementation and the function call like this (if you want to use arrays)

```
void input(struct name info[]);
...
           input(record);
```

Or using pointer (also works with arrays as arguments)

```
void input(struct name *info);
...
           input(record);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this `void input(struct name *info[]);` for your input function. You want to pass a reference to one of the info structs in the array to the function since you only will ever edit one info at a time.

So your altered function would be `void input(struct name *info);` and you would call it using `input(&record[i]);` which gives the address of record i.  You also need to initialize i as you never set it to 0, but incitement it.

Answer (score 1):

another suggestion for you....

use a record counter.... - you have to call the routine for each time you want to add a record. (I have editted the code so you send the routine a pointer to a single record structure, rather than pass the whole structure).

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct age{
    int num;
};

struct name{
    char fname [15];
    char lname[15];
    struct age nameAge;
};

// void input(struct name *info[]);
void input(struct name *info);

int main (void){
char choice;
char ans;
int i;

int n_records=0;

struct name record[10];
do{
    printf("M E N U");
    printf("\n\n[I]nput\n[D]isplay\n[S]earch\n[Q]uit");
    printf("\n\nEnter choice: ");
    choice=tolower(getche());
    system("cls");

    switch (choice){
        case 'i': input(&record[n_records]);
                  i++;
                  nrecords++;
                break;
        case 'd': //function here
                break;
        case 's': //fucntion here
                break;
        case 'q': printf("The program will now close.");
                break;
        default: printf("Invalid character. Try again");
                break;
        }

    getch();
    system("cls");

   }while (choice!='q');
return 0;
}

// void input(struct name *info[]){
void input(struct name *info){
//codes here
}
```